# class fileChooser has no function file browserForFileToOpen()

Tags: c++, juce

Don't know what is the reason behind that error. It is showing that there is no function for chooser class.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lErRv.png

Answer (score 0):

It is because in more recent versions of JUCE, dialog windows which are run modally are turned off by default with the compiler flag `JUCE_MODAL_LOOPS_PERMITTED`.
The method `FileChooser::browseForFileToOpen()` is such a method.

To enable the function add a compile definition to your project (`JUCE_MODAL_LOOPS_PERMITTED=1`) or preferably avoid using this method and choose one of the available-by-default methods like `FileChooser::launchAsync()`.